# The JSON data sent from Javascript is different than the JSON input received in Java Quarkus Service

Tags: javascript, java, json, axios, quarkus

I am developing a simple web application using the `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` which is making a backend call to `Java Quarkus Service` using the `Axios POST request`. Within the `POST request` I am sending the `JSON` data.

The problem I am facing is that the `JSON` data that I am sending is bit different than the data I am receiving in the `Java Quarkus Service`.

I have put a `console.log` just before sending the JSON data to the Java service and the data looks something like this:

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": "abcd"
  },
  "animal": {
    "name": "xyz"
  }
}
```

I have put a `System.out` at the beginning `Java Service` and the data I am receiving there is looking something like this:

```
{
  "inputTemplate": {
    "person": {
      "name": "abcd"
    },
    "animal": {
      "name": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

As we can see the `inputTemplate key` has been added which is not coming up within the `JavaScript`. Not sure why is that.

Following is the call from `Vuejs Axios`, here the `console.log` is working perfectly and `inputTemplate key` is not showing up as described in JSON above.

```
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
const person = { name: 'abcd' }
const animal = { name: 'xyz' }
const inputTemplate = { person, animal}

console.log(JSON.stringify(inputTemplate, null, 4))

this.$axios.post('/generateTestData', { inputTemplate }, { headers })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Response : ' + JSON.stringify(response.data, undefined, '\t'))
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error : ' + ' Unable to obtain data, Error : ' + error)
  })
```

Following is the `Java Quarkus service` where I am getting that additional `inputTemplate key`:

```
  public class TestDataGeneratorResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/generateTestData")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String generateTestData(String inputTemplate) {
        System.out.println(inputTemplate);
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know how to avoid getting the `inputTemplate` within the `Java Service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use spread operator to pass the object : this.$axios.post('/generateTestData', { ...inputTemplate }, { headers })

Comment: I don't know anything about Axios, but I'd say it should be enough to pass just `inputTemplate`, without those curly braces. Technically speaking, `{ inputTemplate }` is equivalent to `{ inputTemplate : inputTemplate }`, so it DOES come from JavaScript.